# .net send raw data to print PInvokeStackImbalance

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing

I try to use this code https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322090 in the visual studio to use a BARCODE printer (Argox OS 214) sending PPLA strings, but it didn't work and display this erro msg: http://gyazo.com/df1eb504d5a7341f5d4072b772c51d84 . Anyone have any idea?

Comment: The KB article code has a bug, it declares OpenPrinter() wrong.  `ByVal pd As Long` is incorrect, change to As IntPtr and pass IntPtr.Zero when you call it.

Comment: Now works, Thanks i print on a 40col imp perfectly, but didn't work for Argox , maybe there is something wrong with the PPLA Strings.